# ASP MVC 3, Razor, create checkboxes for all available roles during user creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox, roles, user-roles

Attempting to get a group of checkboxes for all available Roles using standard ASP.Net Membership provider.  I can successfully get the roles into a single select droplist, but cannot for the life of me get them into a group of check boxes.  I already have how to create roles, delete roles in general, but cannot see how to make a multiselect drop list or a group of checkboxes to select from during new user account creation.  Please note: I am not asking how to handle what checkboxes are check upon the form submission, I believe I have that covered once I get to it.

At any rate, here is what I have at this point, starting with the Models and ViewModels, then on to the CreatUser.cshtml

As you can see, I took the route of a partial view, so that it would render the checkboxes for each item, but I am only getting one empty, as in the name, ID, everything is empty, checkbox at this point.

RoleViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace JustAdminIt.ViewModels
{
    public class RoleViewModel
    {
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

AllRolesViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace JustAdminIt.ViewModels
{
    public class AllRolesViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<RoleViewModel> Roles { get; set; }
    }


}
```

AccountModel.cs - RegisterModel

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Available Roles")]
    public AllRolesViewModel listRoles { get; set; }

}
```

CreatUser.cshtml

```
 @model JustAdminIt.Models.RegisterModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    //var roleDrop = ViewData["roleName"];
}

<h2>Create a New Account</h2>
<p>
    Use the form below to create a new account. 
</p>
<p>
    Passwords are required to be a minimum of @Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength characters in length.<br /><br />
    Passwords are required to contain at least @Membership.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters Non-Alpha-Numeric characters.
</p>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Account creation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                Choose User Role(s)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @foreach(var role in Model.listRoles.Roles)
                {
                    @Html.Label(role.RoleName)
                    @Html.CheckBox(role.RoleName, role.Selected)
                }
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Register" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

**EDIT To Clarify**

I simply need to generate a group of checkboxes on the new user account creation page CreateUser.cshtml so that admins can assign one or more roles during account creation.

Nothing fancy here, but the only examples to be found are creating a droplist of roles, which is not an option on this application.

I cannot find a way to use the Membership provider using Roles.getAllRoles() to enumerate, as that function simply returns a string array of the roles.  I have tried casting it numerous ways etc. to no avail in listing the roles available.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.getallroles.aspx  for reference.  I do not know of another way to get all the roles available.

To clarify the context - RoleViewModel.cs and AllRolesViewModel.cs are in use to list all the system roles on a role admin page - using a partial and it works wonderfully there, but the nature of the checkbox group and html helper dictate a different implementation, and that is what I cannot figure out.

**Edit Updated Code Snippets**

The code snippets listed now are the current in use.  The primary error now, is the entire Model on CreateUser.cshtml is null, unsure why.  Made progress, but still cannot get a group of checkboxes to display for all roles available.

Comment: You have talked so many things and its difficult to find the actual question. Can you highlight exactly what you need?

Answer (score 0):

> I am only getting one empty, as in the name, ID, everything is empty, checkbox at this point.

The reason you are seeing a single blank checkbox is because you are rendering a single partial view with an empty `RoleViewModel` instance passed to it.

```
// This line passes an empty view model...probably not the desired behavior
Html.RenderPartial("_userRoles", new JustAdminIt.ViewModels.RoleViewModel());
```

Given the current structures, I would add an `AllRolesViewModel` property to your `RegisterModel` and then iterate through that with a `foreach`. Inside the `foreach` you can do whatever you want, like creating a partial view, directly creating the checkbox, etc.

```
foreach( var role in Model.AllRolesViewModel.Roles ){
    @Html.CheckBoxFor( role => role.Selected, role.RoleName )
}
```

Taking it a step further, I'm not sure why you need an `AllRolesViewModel` view model if it just contains a collection of roles. You could probably move those roles to the primary view model and omit the intermediary.

### Modifying RegisterModel

> the RegisterModel is the built-in ASP.Net Memebership provider and is
>   not explicitly declared anywhere - how do I add the AllRolesViewModel
>   to that

I believe you are using the auto-generated class which comes with MVC3 scaffolding (see screenshot). You are free to modify this class, even though you are using the ASP.Net membership provider.

[image]

Comment: See, I was wondering about the new RoleViewModel and it being empty.  But couldn't nail it down for sure.  I have attempted the foreach several different ways - will rethink how I was implementing it and likely find I missed using the full model definition.

Comment: OK, so in looking,the AllRolesViewModel to be added to the RegisterModel - the RegisterModel is the built-in ASP.Net Memebership provider and is not explicitly declared anywhere - how do I add the AllRolesViewModel to that?

Comment: that was exactly where my question was - modifying the autogenerated scaffolding.  Will give it a try tomorrow and report back advances.  Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still stuck like nothing.  Simply getting a list of ALL available roles should NOT be this dang difficult.  But, when using the built in provider, Roles.getAllRoles(), it simply returns a string array - which cannot be enumerated by a foreach.  It's not an object, not a list or anything else loopable.

Comment: You can convert it using: `IEnumerable<string> roles = Roles.GetAllRoles().AsEnumerable<string>();`

Comment: .AsEnumerable<string>();  throws an exception.

Comment: Maybe GetAllRoles() is returning null? I just tried `string[] foo = new[] { "1", "2", "3" }; var bar = foo.AsEnumerable<string>();` inside a controller and it worked fine.

Comment: GetAllRoles() is indeed returning the string containing all the roles available, and I can output the string just fine.  Or setup a droplist just fine.  Just can't accomplish the checkbox.